# Validating Array before rendering

Tags: javascript, react.js, jsx

I am rendering a list from an array of objects. I want to check the correctness of the array before rendering. For that I am using typeof and null.

In real situation the list comes from the API.

Is it the correct way? and is there any better way to do it?

```js
const activeEvents = [{
  id: '1',
  title: 'event 1'
}, {
  id: '2',
  title: 'event 2'
}]

function App() {
  return ( <div >
      <h4> List </h4> 
      { typeof activeEvents === 'object' &&
      activeEvents !== null &&
      activeEvents.map(event => ( 
        <li key = { event.id } value = { event.id } > { event.title } 
        </li>
       ))} 
      </div>
);
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typeof activeEvents === 'object' && activeEvents !== null` can be `true` for both `Array` and `Object` :

```js
const array = [];
const obj = {};

console.log(typeof array === 'object' && array !== null)
console.log(typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null)
```

you can use [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```js
const activeEvents = [{
  id: '1',
  title: 'event 1'
}, {
  id: '2',
  title: 'event 2'
}]

function App() {
  return ( 
    <div >
      <h4> List </h4> 
      { Array.isArray(activeEvents) && 
        activeEvents.map(event => ( 
          <li key = { event.id } value = { event.id } > { event.title } </li>
        ))
      } 
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```